# nuxtjs add and remove class on click on elements

Tags: vue.js, onclick, nuxt.js

I am new in vue and nuxt and here is my code I need to update

```html
<template>
  <div class="dashContent">
    <div class="dashContent_item dashContent_item--active">
      <p class="dashContent_text">123</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dashContent_item">
      <p class="dashContent_text">456</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dashContent_item">
      <p class="dashContent_text">789</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
.dashContent {
  &_item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  &_text {
    color: #8e8f93;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
.dashContent_item--active {
  .dashContent_text{
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
</style>
```

I tried something like this:

```
<div @click="onClick">

methods: {
  onClick () {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dashContent_item--active');
  },
},
```

but it changed all elements and I need style change only on element I clicked and remove when click on another
also this code add active class to body not to element I clicked

Comment: You should probably have an array of objects, set a boolean on each one of them, and on-click, toggle this one. Then, conditionally set a class on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to get a togglable list of fruits, with a specific class tied to each one of them.

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <div v-for="(fruit, index) in fruits" :key="fruit.id" @click="toggleEat(index)">
      <span :class="{ 'was-eaten': fruit.eaten }">{{ fruit.name }}</span>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ToggleFruits',
  data() {
    return {
      fruits: [
        { id: 1, name: 'banana', eaten: false },
        { id: 2, name: 'apple', eaten: true },
        { id: 3, name: 'watermelon', eaten: false },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleEat(clickedFruitIndex) {
      this.fruits = this.fruits.map((fruit) => ({
        ...fruit,
        eaten: false,
      }))
      return this.$set(this.fruits, clickedFruitIndex, {
        ...this.fruits[clickedFruitIndex],
        eaten: true,
      })
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.was-eaten {
  color: hsl(24, 81.7%, 49.2%);
}
</style>
```

---

In Vue2, we need to use `this.$set` otherwise, the changed element in a specific position of the array will not be detected. More info available in the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your example works fine, but it has a disadvantage - when you click on it, the active class is added, but it is not removed from the other elements and this is the most important and difficult part of this task for me

Comment: @vvvychikov not that big of a deal. Set all the objects to `false` at first, then toggle the selected one to `true`. Just updated my answer. Kinda radio-button behavior here.